Kotlin/Multik library: class naming and how to index elements in array
Couple of questions related to using multidimensional arrays in Kotlin via the Multik library.
First question: why is it necessary to import both mk and zeros here in order to gain access to mk.zeros? I was thinking that importing mk would be enough. I suppose this is a generic Kotlin question and not specific to Multik. By the way, in this example I am working in the kotlin command line interface on Linux with a suitable classpath containing the Multik stuff.
>>> import org.jetbrains.kotlinx.multik.api.mk
>>> mk.zeros <Double> (4, 3)
error: unresolved reference: zeros
mk.zeros <Double> (4, 3)
   ^
>>> import org.jetbrains.kotlinx.multik.api.zeros
>>> mk.zeros <Double> (4, 3)
res3: org.jetbrains.kotlinx.multik.ndarray.data.NDArray<kotlin.Double, org.jetbrains.kotlinx.multik.ndarray.data.D2> = [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]

Second question, this time specific to Multik. How shall I index the elements of res3, having successfully created it?
>>> res3[0, 0]
error: unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
public operator fun MatchGroupCollection.get(name: String): MatchGroup? defined in kotlin.text
res3[0, 0]
^
error: no get method providing array access
res3[0, 0]
    ^

Looks like there isn't a square brackets operation defined; I wasn't able to find another function for indexing. I'm puzzled since the examples shown in the Multik Github readme (https://github.com/Kotlin/multik) seem to show indexing using square brackets.


zeros is an extension function on Multik (typealias mk), hence you need to explicitly import

Edit
2. res3[0, 0] is incorrect syntax. It should be res3[0][0] 
res[0,0] or res[0][0] works after importing import org.jetbrains.kotlinx.multik.ndarray.data.get

(1) Thanks, that makes sense. (2) Hmm, res3[0][0] doesn't work either; I get the same error, "None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch." For the record, res3 has the type org.jetbrains.kotlinx.multik.ndarray.data.NDArray <kotlin.Double, org.jetbrains.kotlinx.multik.ndarray.data.D2> -- maybe something can be gleaned from that.

You need to also import org.jetbrains.kotlinx.multik.ndarray.data.get for res3[0][0] to work. That's the operator that actually allows you to access res3 as an array with the square brackets syntax.

@Leviathan Thanks, yes, that makes res3[0][0] work, and also res3[0, 0]. I see now that import org.jetbrains.kotlinx.multik.ndarray.data.set is needed to supply the corresponding assignment operator.
